# Python distance matrix

Tags: python, matrix, distance

I would like to create a distance matrix based on a CSV file I have. the matrix is an MxN dataframe. I used the distance_matrix function to have the calculation done, but I am looking for having a way to be able to identify the coordinates as I will be sorting the resulting distance values for the minimum one, hence I need to know the coordinate.

here is an example of the original dataframe from the csv 
`pca=pd.read_csv(yourpath,sep=' ',header=0)`

this results in the below sample

|  | IID | PC1 | PC2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | HG00096 | -0.011791 | 0.024108 |
| 1 | HG00097 | -0.011305 | 0.025150 |
| 2 | HG00099 | -0.011745 | 0.022634 |

when using the distance_matrix function

```
distance=pd.DataFrame(distance_matrix(pca[['PC1','PC2']],pca[['PC1','PC2']]),index=pca['IID'], columns=pca['IID'])
distance
```

I get the below dataframe (as a sample):

| IID | HG00096 | HG00097 | HG00099 | HG00100 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| HG00096 | 0.000000 | 0.001149 | 0.001475 | 0.000299 |
| HG00097 | 0.001149 | 0.000000 | 0.002554 | 0.001362 |
| HG00099 | 0.001475 | 0.002554 | 0.000000 | 0.001205 |

[results from distance_matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opcTi.png)

I was able to change the format of the dataframe by using the to_records() function as per the code below(attached image):

```
distance.to_records()
```

with the following sample result

```
('HG00097', 0.00114949, 0., 0.00255356, 0.00136237, 0.00132839, 0.0008267, 0.00081097, 0.00223232, 0.00061127, 0.00315726, 0.00273763, .....)
```

[results from to_records()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9yZ6.png)

what I am looking to do is to have an array or a list having the two values and their calculated distance. so for example in the results from the distance matrix:

```
HG00096, HG00096,0

HG00096, HG00097, 0.001149
.
.
.
.
.
```

any help on how this can be done?

Comment: Please include the code and test data that you are trying to run. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for tips on this. When you include the data as images it's very difficult for anyone to help you because no one wants to type it all in and possibly introduce a new error.

Comment: thank you so much, i updated the post

Answer (score 0):

Melt it!

You want to use panda's [melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) function, e.g.

```
df = pd.DataFrame( np.random.random((3,3)), columns=list("abc"), index=list('xyz') )

print(df.melt(ignore_index=False))
```

which outputs

```
  variable     value
x        a  0.417710
y        a  0.353251
z        a  0.650867
x        b  0.254477
y        b  0.986522
z        b  0.196494
x        c  0.738882
y        c  0.187359
z        c  0.710457
```

See [melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) for examples of how to keep the ID's together etc.

Please include some random sample data generation to play with next time.

Comment: thank you so much. this worked :)